# Why does alert(1,2,3,...) only show 1?

Tags: javascript

```
function bar(a, b, c, d, e, f) {

  alert(a, b, c, d, e, f)
}

function foo() {

  bar.apply(this, arguments);
}

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```

the above code is alerting 1 ,what is the reason here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `alert` function only uses the first argument it receives.

Your code eventually boils down to:

```
alert(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```

The second and further arguments are ignored because the in-built function doesn't do anything with them.

If you want it to do anything with them, you would have to concatenate them into a single string.

```
function bar(a, b, c, d, e, f) {
    alert(Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, ''));
}
```

Comment: I think the parameter declared in bar are not even significant and can be removed in this case...

Answer (score 3):

The `alert()` function expects only one argument, so it will only show the first one.

If you want to show them all you need to concatenate them into a string:

```
alert(a + "," + b + "," +c);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass all arguments as an array Like :

```
    function bar(a, b, c, d, e, f) {
    var k = [a,b,c,d,e,f];
    alert(k);
    }

    function foo() {
    bar.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```